# How long does my AJAX call take?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something like

```
var date = new Date();
var pretime = date.getTime();

$.post(    
    "ajaxfile.php", 
    object, 
    function(data) {
        var totalTime = date.getTime()-pretime;
        $("#feed").append("Time: " + totalTime + "<br/>" + pretime + "<br/>" + date.getTime() + "<br/>");
    });
});
```

That is, measure how long the AJAXcall lasts before I get a response. But the print from this callback function is:

```
Time: 0
1326184886814
1326184886814
```

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getTime()` is returning the same value because you are reusing the same Date() object. You need to create a new Date object:

```
var date = new Date();
var pretime = date.getTime();
        $.post("ajaxfile.php", object, function(data){
            var date2 = new Date();
            var totalTime = date2.getTime()-pretime;
            $("#feed").append("Time: " + totalTime + "<br/>" + pretime + "<br/>" + date.getTime() + "<br/>");
        });
});
```

Comment: Or just use `Date.now()` to get the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Javascript expert, but it seems to me that you're creating a single `Date` object which (if it's similar to Java's Date object) stores the date/time at the point it was created, and then using that same date object twice - i.e. comparing the start date/time to itself.

Try creating a second `Date` object inside the AJAX callback function to capture the end time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in the time, without saving it somewhere, you can use Google Chrome's developer console.

press F12, go to "Network" tab, execute your Ajax call, and you can see a timeline of how long it takes you to get a response.

Answer (score 0):

If you use firebug to debug your Javascript code take a look at the console. It will tell you how many miliseconds your ajax call takes :)

Also, if you don't use **[firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)**, what are you waiting for? It is awesome for debugging and will save you lots of time!